# ncdump - How do I convert .nc to text without including nodata values?

Tags: netcdf

I have a .nc file that I convert to text using the following command :

```
ncdump in.nc > out.txt
```

However, this particular file has thousands of "-999" values (for nodata). Is there a way to stop ncdump from adding these to the output?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use sed, e.g.,

```
ncdump in.nc | sed -e 's/ -999,//g' > out.txt
ncks in.nc | sed -e 's/_, //g' -e 's/ -999,//g' > out.txt
```

Add `-e` commands until all unwanted patterns disappear.